# Proof for symmetric difference of sets in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that: $A\triangle (B\triangle C) =(A\triangle B) \triangle C$?

The $\triangle$ stands for symmetric difference.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can the statement be proved? My question.

Comment: Yes. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_is_Associative

Comment: Thanks friend. But someone downvoted my question :-(

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I did not downvote. However, it is very likely that your question has been downvoted because the question lacks context. Next time, please try to include your attempts to solve/prove a problem, and include where you encountered the problem, and other details.

Comment: OK OK got it